# Binary Converter Not Working for Large Numbers

Tags: c, binary, type-conversion, largenumber

I'm writing C code that converts from an integer to its binary representation, reverses the binary and then converts back to an integer. It's working well, but I need it to work for input values up to 10^9. Right now, it seems to break for anything larger than 10^7. What I mean is I put in a number such as 10000000 and get out 17967657062982931584 as being the binary representation (despite being accurate for smaller integers). In addition, I am not sure where my int_to_binary is the only function experiencing this problem, or if the others need to be optimized for large inputs as well. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long long int_to_binary(unsigned long long k) {
    if (k == 0) return 0;
    if (k == 1) return 1;
    return (k % 2) + 10 * int_to_binary(k/2);
}

unsigned long long reverse_int(unsigned long long l) {
        unsigned long long reversed; 
    reversed = 0;
        while (l > 0) {
                reversed = reversed * 10 + (l%10);
                l = l / 10;
        }
        return reversed;
}

unsigned long long binary_to_int(unsigned long long k) {
    char binaryString[80];
    snprintf(binaryString, 4, "%llu", k);
    unsigned long long decimal = 0;
    int length = strlen(binaryString);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < length) {
        decimal = (decimal << 1) + (binaryString[i] - 0x30);
        i++;
    }
    return decimal;
}

int main() {
    int number;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("You entered %d\n", number);
    unsigned long long b = int_to_binary(number);
    printf("In Binary, this is %llu\n", b);
    unsigned long long c = reverse_int(b);
    printf("When we reverse it, it looks like this: %llu\n", c);
    unsigned long long d = binary_to_int(c);
    printf("And when we convert that back to an int, it looks like this: %llu\n", d);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would sometimes make sense to convert the integer to bcd (and bco / bch) if not for anything else, but being able to print it with printf. But reversing a binary in base-10 is more than overkill (unless done for academic exercise). And here you've stumbled to the problem that base 10 encoding of a binary takes about log2(10)~=3.32 times longer variable to hold the original.

Comment: Hi @AkiSuihkonen, I am indeed doing this as a challenge presented to me by someone I know, that I found fun. However, the reversing part seems to not be failing (so far); it's more likely the int_to_binary and binary_to_int methods are causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `long long` to represent a binary number as a decimal.  On many architectures this results in the maximum value being stored of 2**64-1 = 18446744073709551615.

If you put in a decimal number such as 10000000, it cannot be represented as a decimal-binary number in 64 bits.

Comment: Depends on what you're use the result for.  If it's for display purposes, just create a `char*` array with the results of the binary conversion.  Each item in the array would store a '0' or '1' ASCII character.

Comment: I definitely need some way to grab this binary value and manipulate it, if I want my program to work. The question is, once I create this char* array, how do I convert/use it as a decimal/int/long of some sort?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question.  The number entered by the user is already converted to binary with your `scanf` call and represented as a C `int`.  You can manipulate this `int` directly using operators such as `|` and `&`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The OP was going with the idea of decimal-binary.  I was attempting to suggest a different approach.

Comment: @AustinPhillips, if it is just to hold the bits, just store a 0 or 1 for each bit in an int (or char) array.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is attempting to manipulate a binary number as a sum of powers of ten. It's more efficient to manipulate binary directly. Just change `10` to `2` in the `reverse_int` function.

```
unsigned long long reverse_int(unsigned long long l) {
        unsigned long long reversed; 
        reversed = 0;
        while (l > 0) {
                reversed = reversed * 2 + (l%2);
                l = l / 2;
        }
        return reversed;
}
```

In order to print numbers in binary, write a loop, testing each bit in sequence, using modulo `%` or bitwise operators like `&` and `>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the main problems I'm experiencing aren't in this function, but rather in the int_to_binary function and the binary_to_int function. What Austin Phillips suggested is a good idea, and I was able to successfully make a char* array that holds the number; however, since I want to manipulate it, I tried converting it back into a long long, which again led me to the same problem. I think the issue lies with what the long long type is capable of storing.

Comment: @RMartin Yes, the purpose of this suggestion is to work within the limits of `long long` (or indeed `long` also suffices).

Comment: Yes, and this works for the reverse function, but it doesn't apply to the int_to_binary function, which is where the long seems to be being truncated (or otherwise garbled).

Comment: @RMartin The solution is not to do that, and dispel any notion of converting things to decimal inside an integral type like "long." Conversion to a particular base should only be done while printing a number.

Comment: ....But that doesn't help. I *need* to convert any integer into binary, and be able to reverse/mirror the binary number, and convert that back to a base ten number.

Comment: @RMartin Integers aren't inherently in a base. If I have five chickens, are they in base 2 or base 10? The task of "converting an integer to binary" and getting another integer is fundamentally nonsense. Obtaining the number *represented* by a reversed binary *representation* is what this function does. Printing the binary representation would be another function. But a number doesn't have a base, only its representation does.